# question to set relation between angles and arcs in circles

Tags: geometry

In the following figure how do I prove that $\angle AOC=\frac{\mathrm{arc}AC+\mathrm{arc}BD}{2}$ [image]

Comment: How can an angle and arc be equated ?  If $a$ is radius of arc  you mean  $ 2 a AOC={\mathrm{arc}AC+\mathrm{arc}BD} ? $

Answer (score 0):

In $\triangle COB$, we have $\angle AOC=\angle DCB+\angle CBA$.

But $\angle DCB=\frac{\mathrm{arc}BD}{2}$ and $\angle CBA=\frac{\mathrm{arc}AC}{2}$.

Here we're using the fact that inscrite angles are one half of the central angle, and measure of central angle is, by definition, measure of the central angle.

Comment: how $\triangle ABO$?please elaborate your second line.I only want to understand second line.

Comment: It was a typing error. Thanks for your correction

Comment: Why $\angle DCB=\frac{\mathrm{arc}BD}{2}$

Comment: I'll repeat you: Let $Q$ the center of the circle. Then, by definition, $\mathrm{arc}BD=\angle BQD$. But it is easly to show that every inscibed angle in the $\mathrm{arc}BD$ measures $\frac{\angle BQD}{2}=\frac{\mathrm{arc}BD}{2}$

Comment: Still I want to ask that  is there no proof of this statement?please reply, this is last time.

Comment: Ok. Remember: \mathrm{arc}BD=\angle BQD by definition. This is a fact that don't need proof. Now, for inscribed angles, read carefully https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle . It seems more difficult that really is.